# Where to remove an ADC bias?

Tags: arduino-uno, adc

I'm using several ACS712-based 5A current sensors. They're non-polar and so (I gather) the output is biased to Vcc/2 to allow a swing in either direction. The sensor outputs +/- 185mV/A, plus the bias.

The example sketch I've seen does a computation like `amps = ((analogRead(A0) * 5.0) / 1023) - 2.5` (where 2.5v is the bias).

In my case the actual current value and polarity aren't important, just the presence of current. Is there anything untoward about doing this instead?

```
boolean isCurrent = (abs(analogRead(A0) - 512) > thresholdValue);
```

This avoids floating point (unless `abs()` forces it?) and an ADC count of 512 should be equivalent to a bias of Vcc/2. The threshold just cores out some noise / jitter / drift. Seem OK? Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: yes, but most (all?) of the "negative" is noise anyway right? or is the flow reversible?

Comment: @dandavis - For any given sensor the flow will be one-way, but I can't assume that all will be wired the same. There are 12+ of these and their inputs will arrive as pairs of black wires. Since the reading code is common to all (in a loop), I have to accommodate both polarities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing untoward about that - it is perfectly acceptable and, in fact recommended, since as you note it uses no floating point.